# search page not found? (search.php or searchpage.php)

Tags: search, templates

Am i wrong in thinking i can access the search page by using /search/ ? I've created the files search.php & searchpage.php but /search/ still returns 404?

I want to customise the page a bit...

best, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access search pages via `search/foo` as well as `?s=foo`. This search rewrite rule is built in into WP since version 1.5. I tested it and it works.

As for the template files, you will need `search.php`, `searchpage.php` is not used.

Also see:

- http://alexking.org/blog/2007/08/30/friendly-search-urls#comment-57678
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Answer (score 0):

You can not access search page like this.To access search page you have to enter your blog name in URL box of browser followed by ?s= any search keyword.

Example :

```
http://localhost/wordpress/?s=video
```

Comment: ok - so i'll just have to create a file page-search.php and create a page called search in the admin to create a custom page then. Cheers... Dc